# sql server 2008 how do i disconnect everyone from my db?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to rename the database, but I cannot since other processes is using it. I don't care about the process, and I need to kill it.

How do I remove all connections from the db?

Comment: i tried to do what you all suggested but i am getting DB is alr3ady open and can only have one user at atime

Comment: Don't try and rename it through Object Explorer that will use a different connection. You need to use TSQL.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per my comment once in `single_user` mode you need to do the rename from the same connection. Don't try and rename it through Object Explorer as that will try and open up a new connection. The following works this end...

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks SET single_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks MODIFY NAME = NewAdventureWorks

ALTER DATABASE NewAdventureWorks SET multi_user
```

Comment: Just a note that this works for MS SQL 2005 and above. For those that still work on previous version you would need to use `EXEC sp_dboption 'DB name', 'single user', 'TRUE'`

Answer (score 9):

Like this: [Kill All Active Connections To A Database](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Kill_All_Active_Connections_To_A_Database)

```
ALTER DATABASE oldNameSET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

EXEC sp_renamedb 'oldName', 'newName'

ALTER DATABASE newName SET MULTI_USER  --new name of course
```

Answer (score 2):

Run sp_who, then kill [pid] for everyone in your database.

Comment: This is tedious, cumbersome, and while you're doing that 500 more spids could connect to your server. Ever play whack-a-mole? Set the database to SINGLE_USER - it's a single command and blocks new connections from coming in.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me to rename database and force disconnect everybody:

```
ALTER DATABASE [old_name]
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [old_name]
    MODIFY NAME = [new_name]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [new_name]
    SET MULTI_USER
GO
```